# Convert list to tibble in R with NULL values

Tags: list, null, tibble

```
library(tidyverse)

event <- list(
  reportId = 157250,
  eventId = 4580,
  country = "Moldova",
  disease = "African swine fever",
  subType = NULL
)

event %>% as_tibble()
```

An error raised:

- ! All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
- ✖ Column `subType` is NULL.

There are thousands of events list like this, is any method to get a tibble object  properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can circumvent this by running the following steps:

```
event %>% 
  enframe() %>% # long format with all elements as lists
  unnest("value", keep_empty = TRUE) %>% # transform into elementary data
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value") # make wide format with all columns
```

Answer (score 0):

use `map_df` can generate a tibble object, however, the column with NULL missed.

```
event %>% map_df(.f = ~.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement; I have a list obtained from the FlightAware API (converted from JSON) that contains NULLs.

The solution by @manuela-benary did not work straight away because the response includes a nested array of alternatives; here is the specification for the response from the [API documentation](https://flightaware.com/aeroapi/portal/documentation#get-/operators/-id-):

```
{
  "icao": "string",
  "iata": "string",
  "callsign": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "country": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "phone": "string",
  "shortname": "string",
  "url": "string",
  "wiki_url": "string",
  "alternatives": [
    {
      "icao": "string",
      "iata": "string",
      "callsign": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "country": "string",
      "location": "string",
      "phone": "string",
      "shortname": "string",
      "url": "string",
      "wiki_url": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

This simply required running Manuela's code on the `alternatives` list first, then NULLing that member of the response, and then running the code on the original list. The two sets of results can then be `row_bind()`ed together.